# Non linear regression for exponential decay model in R

Tags: r, loops, sum, regression, non-linear-regression

I have the following problem:

I asked 5 people (i=1, ..., 5) to forecast next period's return of 3 different stocks. This gives me the following data:

```
S_11_i_c <-read.table(text = "
             i     c_1       c_2         c_3 
             1     0.150    0.70        0.190 
             2     0.155    0.70        0.200 
             3     0.150    0.75        0.195 
             4     0.160    0.80        0.190 
             5     0.150    0.75        0.180 
               ",header = T)
```

In words, in period `t=10` participant `i=1` expects the return of stock `c_1` to be `0.15` in period `t=11`.

The forecasts are based on past returns of the stocks. These are the following:

```
S_t_c <-read.table(text = "
 time     S_c_1     S_c_2          S_c_3 
     1     0.020    0.015         0.040 
     2     0.045    0.030         0.050 
     3     0.060    0.045         0.060 
     4     0.075    0.060         0.060 
     5     0.090    0.070         0.060 
     6     0.105    0.070         0.090 
     7     0.120    0.070         0.120 
     8     0.125    0.070         0.140 
     9     0.130    0.070         0.160 
    10     0.145    0.070         0.180 
           ",header = T)
```

In words, stock c=1 had a return of 0.145 in period 10.

So, the variables in table S_11_i_c are the dependent variables.
The variables in table S_t_c are the independet variables.

The model I want to estimate is the following:

[image]

[image]

My problem with coding this is as follows:

I do only know how to express [image]

with the help of a loop. As in:

```
Sum_S_t_c <- data.frame(
    s = seq(1:9),
    c_1 = rnorm(9)  
    c_2 = rnorm(9)
    c_3 = rnorm(9)

)

Sum_S_t_c = 0
for (c in 2:4) {
    for (s in 0:9) {  
    Sum_S_t_c[s,c] <- Sum_S_t_c + S_t_c[10-s, c] 
    Sum_S_t_c = Sum_S_t_c[s,c]
    }
}
```

However, loops within a regression are not possible. So, my other solution would be to rewrite the sum to [image]

However, as my actual problem has a much larger n, this isn*t realy working for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that there is a `sum` function in R?

Comment: @Roland yes, but let's say I have to following data: x <- `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` . I know what `sum(x)` gives me, namely: 15. But how can I use the sum function to get: `1^4+2^3+3^2+4^1+5^0?`

Comment: `sum((1:5)^(4:0))`

Comment: I don't understand how `beta_2 ^j` is defined

Comment: @Cettt it's sum((beta_2)^(0:9))

Comment: yeah, but what is beta_2?

Comment: @Cettt It's one of the parmaters I want to estimate. So bascially a weighting parameter.